# Angular animation when model content changes

Tags: angular, animation

I'm building an Angular 7 app. I have a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
      "title": "Hello",      
      "description": "Lorem ipsum"
  },
  {
      "title": "Hi",      
      "description": "Dolor amet"
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm parsing this JSON to my model:

item.model.ts

```
export class Item {
  public title: string;
  public description: string;
}
```

In my app, when I click on the buttons "next" and "previous", I change the content on screen, like this:

app.component.ts

```
  public items: Array<Item> = [];
  public currentItem: number;

  next() {
    this.currentItem++;
  }

  previous() {
    this.currentItem--;
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ items[currentItem]?.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ items[currentItem]?.description}}</p>
</div>
<button (click)="next()"> <button (click)="previous()">
```

It is working as expected.

Now I want to add a animation on it (slide from right to left when click on "next", and slide left to right when click on "previous").

I read a thousand of examples using ngFor, ngIf and so on, but in my case I dont have any of these directives. I should trigger the animation when the content of my model changes, or when the button is clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: Write the CSS animation to accomplish your goal and then just toggle the class via NgClass on property change.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

the below code is an example of animation, you can add animation by following this.

app.component.ts

```js
public nextClass = false;
public preClass= false;
next() {
    this.nextClass = false;
    this.nextClass = true;
    this.preClass = false;
    this.currentItem++;
  }

  previous() {
    this.preClass = false;
    this.nextClass = false;
    this.preClass = true;
    this.currentItem--;
  }
```

app.component.html

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'next':nextClass, 'pre':preClass}">
  <h1>{{ items[currentItem]?.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ items[currentItem]?.description}}</p>
</div>
<button (click)="next()"> <button (click)="previous()">
```

app.component.scss

```
::ng-deep{
.next{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: myfirst 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes myfirst {
    from {width: 0px;}
    to {width: 100px; background-color: blue;}
}
}
```